# C#/AvaloniaUI - OpenFolderDialog

Tags: c#, wpf, avaloniaui

I am using AvaloniaUI and I am trying to implement: http://avaloniaui.net/api/Avalonia.Controls/OpenFolderDialog/

What I want to achieve is when I press a button and it triggers `openFold` to show up a dialog making me choose a directory. Once I select a directory I want to store it's path in `var result`.

Here is my code:

```
public async Task openFold()
{
    var dialog = new OpenFolderDialog();
    var result = await dialog.ShowAsync();

    if (result != null)
    {
        await openFold(result);
    }
    Trace.WriteLine("DIR IS: " + result);
}
```

However I don't know how to pass the current main window to `ShowAsync`.

I am not sure that even if I pass the current window to `ShowAsync` it will show up a choose directory dialog. Am I doing it correctly ?

Comment: This looks infinitely recursive to me.  As for passing the window, looks like it just takes it as a [parameter](http://avaloniaui.net/api/Avalonia.Controls/OpenFolderDialog/126982C2).

Comment: @Zer0 can you form a complete answer ? The question is how to get that parameter to pass it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just checked an AvaloniaUI app where I run your code (except `await openFold(result)` since you didn't provide the implementation of that method).

Nevertheless, everything works perfectly, I'm getting the folder selection window open, I can choose the folder and it is returned in `result`.

It works both with the `window` parameter given and without, as it is optional.

If the `openFold()` method is defined within the `MainWindow` class, you simply run
`var result = await dialog.ShowAsync(this);`

Should you want to place the method somewhere else, create a static accessor variable for the main window:
`public static MainWindow Instance;`
Assign it in the constructor:
`Instance = this;`
and call your folder selection window by:
`var result = await dialog.ShowAsync(MainWindow.Instance);`

Or did I misunderstood your problem?

Comment: Hey @Mike are you sure this will gonna work on Linux and Mac as well ?

Comment: I'd give it a try - I'm not sure however I explicitly didn't put any Windows-specific methods there.